# Regex to replace non-numeric characters and insert dashes for phone number as it is typed

Tags: javascript, regex

I need javascript to format a telephone number as it is typed. This would replace all non-numeric characters and insert dashes if the user doesn't type them in. So far this is the closest I've gotten, but it is thrown off if they put a dash in the wrong spot. The ideal solution would be to replace dashes only in the wrong spots. I was looking for a way to possibly replace the 4th and the 8th digit differently but haven't come up with a solution.

```
$('#TelephoneNo').keyup(function (ev) {
        if (/[^0-9\-]/g.test(this.value))
        {
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\-]/g, '');
        }

        if (/^(\d{3})(\d)/.test(this.value))
        {
            this.value = this.value.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d)/, '$1-$2');
        }

        if (/^(\d{3}-\d{3})(\d)/.test(this.value))
        {
            this.value = this.value.replace(/^(\d{3}-\d{3})(\d)/, '$1-$2');
        }
    });
```

Comment: I strongly recommend https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/tree/master/javascript it will save you time and headache!

Comment: Another great option is jQuery Mask: https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the format "123-456-7890":

```
function formatPhoneNumber(s) {
  var s2 = (""+s).replace(/\D/g, '');
  var m = s2.match(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/);
  return (!m) ? null : m[1] + " -" + m[2] + "-" + m[3];
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works as the number is being typed since I get null unless there are 10 numbers

Comment: can you give me your expected output

Comment: 999-999-9999 format is correct. Event occurs every time a character is typed. If the user types 1234 it changes text to 123-4, if the user types 123-4567 the text is changed to 123-456-7.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function CheckNum(ev) {
 var inputval=document.getElementById("TelephoneNo").value;
  debugger
 if(inputval){
        if (/[^0-9\-]/g.test(inputval))
        {
            inputval = inputval.replace(/[^0-9\-]/g, '');
        }
        if(detectPosition()){
        if (/^(\d{3})(\d)/.test(inputval))
        {
            inputval = inputval.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d)/, '$1-$2');
        }

        if (/^(\d{3}-\d{3})(\d)/.test(inputval))
        {
            inputval = inputval.replace(/^(\d{3}-\d{3})(\d)/, '$1-$2');
        }
        }
        document.getElementById("TelephoneNo").value=inputval;
    }
}

function detectPosition() {   var inputval=document.getElementById("TelephoneNo").value;   
 if(inputval.indexOf("-") ==4 || inputval.indexOf("-") ==8)
 {
  return 1;
 }
  return -1;
 }
</script>

</head>
<body>        
<input type="text" id="TelephoneNo" onkeyup="CheckNum(this)">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah that code works unless the user types a dash in the wrong spot. for example 99-99 will stop formatting altogether. I need a solution that formats dashes to match 999-999-9999 even if the number is partially typed.

Comment: If doesn't allow user to type "-" then there is not possibility of incorrect

Comment: if I use /[^0-9]/g it continuously deletes the dash if they are determined to format it themselves which might be confusing. Perhaps if the dash inserted right after three numbers instead of waiting for the fourth.

Comment: if(inputval.indexOf("-") ==4 || inputval.indexOf("-") ==8)
 {
  alert(inputval.indexOf("-")); 
 }

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I figured I might help someone out.

I did this xxx-xxx-xxxx as-you-type formatting using two cases: one for formatting where the length required one hyphen, and another for formatting with two required. That way, the last group always expects an unknown char count and doesn't wait until the end of the user input to enforce the format.

```js
function formatPhone() {
  var element = document.getElementById('phone');
  var inputValue = element.value;
  
  // length < 3 : no formatting necessary
  if (inputValue.length > 3 && inputValue.length < 8)
    // length < 8 : only one hyphen necessary, after first group of 3
    // replace (remove) non-digits, then format groups 1 and 2
    result = inputValue.replace(/\D/gi, '').replace(/(.{3})(.{0,3})/g, '$1-$2');
  else
    // length >= 8 : 2 hyphens required, after first two groups of 3
    // replace (remove) non-digits, then format groups 1, 2, and 3
    result = inputValue.replace(/\D/gi, '').replace(/(.{3})(.{3})(.{0,4})/g, '$1-$2-$3');
    
  element.value = result;
}
```

```html
Type a phone number, it will be formatted to xxx-xxx-xxxx as you type:<br/><br/>
<input type="text" id="phone" maxlength="12" onkeyup="formatPhone()"></input>
```